# Use paperclip to define thumb version of image keeping aspect ratio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm implementing paperclip and the images I'll be uploading have different sizes.  I want each image's thumbnail to be 100 pixels tall and to keep the aspect ratio of the uploaded image.  Is there a way to define that criteria in a statement like the following?

```
 has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :standard => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
```

Would something like the following work:

```
:styles => lambda { |a|
                    height_quotient = a.instance.height / 100    
                    { :thumb => "#{(a.instance.width / height_quotient) }x100#" }
                  }
```

I'm going to try this out but please provide feedback if you see an issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default resize option seems to keep the aspect ratio.  For example:

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :standard => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
```

resizes the image with the appropriate aspect ratio when `@object.image.url(:standard)` is called.